# How to add profile variable in Karate

Tags: karate, intuit-partner-platform

Currently I am using the following command to run my feature file:

```
mvn test -Dcucumber.options="--plugin html:target/cucumber-html --tags @dogs" -Dtest=TestParallel.java  -Dkarate.env=Pets
```

But I wish to add another variable while calling running the command. Something like this:

```
mvn test -Dcucumber.options="--plugin html:target/cucumber-html --tags @dogs" -Dtest=TestParallel.java  -Dkarate.env=Pets -Dname=Charlie
```

How can I do that?

Comment: @PeterThomas done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass extra dynamic parameters using a combination of Java system-properties and reading [`karate.properties`](https://github.com/intuit/karate#karate-properties)

```
mvn test -Dtest=TestParallel.java  -Dkarate.env=pets -Dmy.name=foo
```

And then in `karate-config.js`

```
var myName = karate.properties['my.name'];
```

Or even in any feature file:

```
* def myName = karate.properties['my.name']
```

Kindly do note that `-Dcucumber.options="--plugin html:target/cucumber-html"` does not have any effect in Karate and [will be deprecated](https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/444) in the future.